# Convert Table of latitude, longitude and values to 2-D grid of lat, long and values

Tags: python, numpy

In the following data, the first column is longitude, the second column is latitude, and from the third column to the last column, there  is  monthly data  from January to December in that particular lat and long grid.

```
  123.00   52.50 0.8808496E+03 0.7983786E+03 0.8826313E+03 0.8459452E+03 0.8619072E+03 0.8350419E+03 0.8608338E+03 0.8610720E+03 0.8383484E+03 0.8741709E+03 0.8564337E+03 0.8842023E+03
  123.25   52.50 0.1667402E+03 0.1520321E+03 0.1676579E+03 0.1580190E+03 0.1569843E+03 0.1524035E+03 0.1564315E+03 0.1565542E+03 0.1541065E+03 0.1633005E+03 0.1634209E+03 0.1684670E+03
  123.50   52.50 0.6747873E+03 0.6210926E+03 0.6822463E+03 0.6258512E+03 0.5954875E+03 0.5802058E+03 0.5909939E+03 0.5919910E+03 0.5940483E+03 0.6468277E+03 0.6697598E+03 0.6888232E+03
  123.75   52.50 0.2467868E+04 0.2271493E+04 0.2495147E+04 0.2288896E+04 0.2177849E+04 0.2121960E+04 0.2161414E+04 0.2165062E+04 0.2172585E+04 0.2365612E+04 0.2449481E+04 0.2519201E+04
  124.00   52.50 0.1109248E+04 0.1020982E+04 0.1121510E+04 0.1028805E+04 0.9788915E+03 0.9537708E+03 0.9715045E+03 0.9731437E+03 0.9765255E+03 0.1063287E+04 0.1100984E+04 0.1132321E+04
  124.25   52.50 0.3159128E+03 0.2907748E+03 0.3194048E+03 0.2930025E+03 0.2787873E+03 0.2716329E+03 0.2766835E+03 0.2771504E+03 0.2781134E+03 0.3028230E+03 0.3135591E+03 0.3224839E+03
  124.50   52.50 0.1338592E+04 0.1232077E+04 0.1353389E+04 0.1241516E+04 0.1181283E+04 0.1150969E+04 0.1172369E+04 0.1174347E+04 0.1178428E+04 0.1283128E+04 0.1328619E+04 0.1366436E+04
  124.75   52.50 0.7045669E+03 0.6388000E+03 0.7061202E+03 0.6761815E+03 0.6880540E+03 0.6666766E+03 0.6871183E+03 0.6873259E+03 0.6695590E+03 0.6987448E+03 0.6853247E+03 0.7074897E+03
  125.00   52.50 0.3381786E+04 0.3059350E+04 0.3384892E+04 0.3261380E+04 0.3348760E+04 0.3242371E+04 0.3346889E+04 0.3347304E+04 0.3248136E+04 0.3370142E+04 0.3279667E+04 0.3387631E+04
  125.25   52.50 0.1961657E+04 0.1781027E+04 0.1967574E+04 0.1876828E+04 0.1898756E+04 0.1840622E+04 0.1895192E+04 0.1895983E+04 0.1851602E+04 0.1939479E+04 0.1911656E+04 0.1972791E+04
  125.50   52.50 0.1072950E+03 0.9878714E+02 0.1084769E+03 0.9711996E+02 0.9447763E+02 0.9202362E+02 0.9307782E+02 0.9390406E+02 0.9427554E+02 0.1027549E+03 0.1064984E+03 0.1095190E+03
  125.75   52.50 0.1514417E+03 0.1394381E+03 0.1531092E+03 0.1370604E+03 0.1333164E+03 0.1293685E+03 0.1313361E+03 0.1325040E+03 0.1330356E+03 0.1450181E+03 0.1503177E+03 0.1545795E+03
  126.00   52.50 0.4479888E+03 0.4084135E+03 0.4529629E+03 0.4214777E+03 0.4226213E+03 0.4140549E+03 0.4204238E+03 0.4224188E+03 0.4175742E+03 0.4413225E+03 0.4433801E+03 0.4573489E+03
  126.25   52.50 0.1038578E+02 0.9562582E+01 0.1050013E+02 0.9399520E+01 0.9142758E+01 0.8872013E+01 0.9006948E+01 0.9087042E+01 0.9123500E+01 0.9945253E+01 0.1030870E+02 0.1060096E+02
   98.50   52.25 0.2600510E+01 0.2401866E+01 0.2600510E+01 0.2534295E+01 0.2317481E+01 0.2166105E+01 0.2232320E+01 0.2270205E+01 0.2251266E+01 0.2440210E+01 0.2534295E+01 0.2600510E+01
   99.25   52.25 0.2019357E+02 0.1865105E+02 0.2019357E+02 0.1967939E+02 0.1799578E+02 0.1682032E+02 0.1733449E+02 0.1762867E+02 0.1748161E+02 0.1894880E+02 0.1967939E+02 0.2019357E+02
  120.75   52.25 0.2512760E+02 0.2285111E+02 0.2528853E+02 0.2298190E+02 0.2178992E+02 0.2072507E+02 0.2038844E+02 0.2111930E+02 0.2130790E+02 0.2376282E+02 0.2485684E+02 0.2504733E+02
  121.00   52.25 0.8857477E+03 0.8055014E+03 0.8914200E+03 0.8101117E+03 0.7680945E+03 0.7305585E+03 0.7186925E+03 0.7444552E+03 0.7511031E+03 0.8376392E+03 0.8762033E+03 0.8829180E+03
  121.25   52.25 0.2084019E+04 0.1895213E+04 0.2097365E+04 0.1906060E+04 0.1807200E+04 0.1718884E+04 0.1690965E+04 0.1751581E+04 0.1767222E+04 0.1970827E+04 0.2061562E+04 0.2077361E+04
  121.50   52.25 0.7002205E+03 0.6367824E+03 0.7047048E+03 0.6404270E+03 0.6072106E+03 0.5775369E+03 0.5681562E+03 0.5885227E+03 0.5937784E+03 0.6621887E+03 0.6926752E+03 0.6979835E+03
  121.75   52.25 0.1565343E+04 0.1423671E+04 0.1575358E+04 0.1431346E+04 0.1356564E+04 0.1277269E+04 0.1269264E+04 0.1314830E+04 0.1326676E+04 0.1480163E+04 0.1548493E+04 0.1560347E+04
  122.00   52.25 0.8609155E+03 0.7802265E+03 0.8635948E+03 0.8108029E+03 0.8050565E+03 0.7695794E+03 0.7816993E+03 0.7938904E+03 0.7827984E+03 0.8381255E+03 0.8421456E+03 0.8595789E+03
  122.25   52.25 0.1371758E+04 0.1241285E+04 0.1374083E+04 0.1308128E+04 0.1323301E+04 0.1272367E+04 0.1303039E+04 0.1313615E+04 0.1283834E+04 0.1351988E+04 0.1335317E+04 0.1370599E+04
  122.50   52.25 0.8593264E+03 0.7785834E+03 0.8617936E+03 0.8110353E+03 0.8078933E+03 0.7730782E+03 0.7863868E+03 0.7976119E+03 0.7852496E+03 0.8383423E+03 0.8398946E+03 0.8580957E+03
  122.75   52.25 0.5374568E+02 0.4888142E+02 0.5408952E+02 0.4914493E+02 0.4657730E+02 0.4385473E+02 0.4357987E+02 0.4514437E+02 0.4555110E+02 0.5082106E+02 0.5316713E+02 0.5357415E+02
  123.00   52.25 0.4366411E+03 0.3952134E+03 0.4371731E+03 0.4206180E+03 0.4309849E+03 0.4173623E+03 0.4306644E+03 0.4307356E+03 0.4183496E+03 0.4346468E+03 0.4237498E+03 0.4376422E+03
  123.25   52.25 0.5455102E+03 0.5015980E+03 0.5512159E+03 0.5071299E+03 0.4848490E+03 0.4722130E+03 0.4814114E+03 0.4821741E+03 0.4828020E+03 0.5241220E+03 0.5407183E+03 0.5562471E+03
  123.50   52.25 0.3113906E+03 0.2866125E+03 0.3148327E+03 0.2888084E+03 0.2747966E+03 0.2677446E+03 0.2727229E+03 0.2731830E+03 0.2741324E+03 0.2984882E+03 0.3090706E+03 0.3178677E+03
```

From this data, I want to make a separate 2-D array of  latitude, longitude and data  of a individual month. I am able to extract the column of   latitude  and longitude values and make their 2-D grid using the following code:

```
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(np.unique(longitude),np.unique(latitude))
```

But, I am having a hard time trying to make a 2-D grid of a particular month that corresponds to these 2-D lat and long values.
I did try the following link [Python numpy: create 2d array of values based on coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165359/lat-lon-values-csv-to-raster-map-using-python). But, I couldn't plot the values  since the coordinates are in floats rather than integer and the data aren't properly arranged and there are  only values that are available in particular lat and long grid with a lot of missing data in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the following about your data:

1. Your data is a matrix of n rows and 14 columns where columns 1 and 2 are latitude and longitude data.
2. Next I assume each month is follows in order i.e. column 3 is Jan, 4 is Feb, e.t.c.

With this, we can extract the requisite data via fancy indexing.
The general format is:

```py
month_data = data[:, [0, 1, month_column]]
```

Some concrete examples are:

```py
january_data = data[:, [0, 1, 2]]
february_data = data[:, [0, 1, 3]]
july_data = data[:, [0, 1, 8]]
```